# Returning an odata IQueryable object that differs to the query options

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to get the following code to work

```
        public IQueryable<BankingDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TillSummaryDTO> options)
        {
            return((IQueryable<BankingDTO>)options.ApplyTo(this._bankingService.GetBanking()));    
        }
```

I would like to query on TillSummaryDTO because it has the field "TillOpID" on it. However I would like to return BankingDTO as this is the end result which contains the group by and sum. When I run the query I receive the error "Cannot apply ODataQueryOptions of 'Bepoz.Presentation.ViewModels.TillSummaryDTO' to IQueryable of 'Bepoz.Presentation.ViewModels.BankingDTO" what is the best practice for this?

The bankingservice.GetBanking method looks like this

```
    var query = from t in _tillSummaryRepository.Table
        join w in _workStationRepository.Table on t.TillOpID equals w.WorkstationID
        join s in _storeRepository.Table on w.StoreID equals s.StoreID
        join v in _venueRepository.Table on s.VenueID equals v.VenueID
        select new TillSummaryDTO
        {
            TillOpID = t.TillOpID,
            Cash = t.Cash,
            Workstation = new WorkstationDTO()
            {
                WorkstationID = w.WorkstationID,
                Name = w.Name,
                Store = new StoreDTO()
                {
                    StoreID = s.StoreID,
                    StoreGroup = s.StoreGroup,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Venue = new VenueDTO()
                    {
                        VenueID = v.VenueID,
                        VenueGroup = v.VenueGroup,
                        Name = v.Name,
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    return query.GroupBy(x => x.Workstation.Name)
        .Select(x => new BankingDTO()
        {
            TotalCash = x.Sum(y => y.Cash),
            WorkstationName = x.Key
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you want to achieve is that you have an entity set of TillSummaryDTO that you want to query, and you would like the return type to be a collection of BankingDTO. The query for the BankingDTO is carried out by applying the query options in the URL onto TillSummaryDTO   . But the fact that the BankingDTO and TillSummaryDTO are different kind of types makes it impossible achieve that in a simple Get action method, right?

This scenario can be better resolved by the function feature of the OData protocol that the function takes the TillSummaryDTO collection as input parameter, has some internal complicated logic to query for the right BankingDTO, and returns the BankingDTO instead of TillSummaryDTO.

For the concept of function in OData protocol, you can refer to [this link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793740) for V4 and section "10.4.2. Functions" of [this page](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol) for V3.

For implementation, [this sample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/) can be referred to for Web API OData V4 and [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/odata-actions) can be referred to for Web API OData V3.